# When would `initiator` be undefined in the details of a request callback

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Per documentation here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest

The initiator (which is usually the domain where the request is been made) is `optional`, and since I use TypeScript, the typing interface also stated that the `initiator` value could be `string | undefined`.

Under what circumstances would the `initiator` value be `undefined`? I searched around and couldn't find any helpful answers.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the [source code](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/extensions/browser/api/web_request/web_request_info.h?l=119-121&rcl=67e64c3a):

> May be null for browser-initiated requests such as navigations.

It means the main request for the page itself. Such request doesn't have an owner/initiator as the purpose of this property is to attribute sub-resources to their owning page URL in order to decide whether an extension has the right to intrude.

Here's a typical request for the page itself as seen in onBeforeRequest listener:

```json
{
  "frameId": 0,
  "method": "GET",
  "parentFrameId": -1,
  "requestId": "86",
  "tabId": 15,
  "timeStamp": 1551468325912.045,
  "type": "main_frame",
  "url": "https://github.com/"
}
```

Maybe you could simply declare the property as optional in your TS code.